# Are there any open source command line tools to refactor java code?

Tags: java, command-line, refactoring, automated-refactoring

I use vim as my editor but I would like to get some of the same power of the IDE's for java when it comes to refactoring. Are there any commandline tools for refactoring java? I could probably hack something together using perl or vim scripting but if there is something already out there I'd rather use that.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: mostly just renaming classes, methods and variables across files. That's my most common use case.

Comment: are there any not open source command line tools? Any tools would be nice.

Comment: Not open source, but may do some of  what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119760/automatic-code-simplification-via-refactoring

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [jrefactory](http://jrefactory.sourceforge.net/csrefactory.html), and its [command line option](http://jrefactory.sourceforge.net/csr-commandline.html).

Comment: Yeah, not that sophisticated. I use IntelliJ and Netbeans, though.

Answer (score 7):

You could try [Eclim](http://eclim.org/). The goal of Eclim is to expose the functionality of Eclipse within Vim. In particular, there are a few [commands for refactoring](http://eclim.org/vim/java/refactor.html) that are supported.

Answer (score 1):

Code refactoring is a very context-sensitive and interaction-heavy process which doesn't lend itself very well to command-line interfaces. There can be dozens of types of refactorings you could do to a particular file (or set of files) and coming up with a vim interface to integrate all of this would be a major challenge.

If you want IDE functionality, why not use an IDE? Especially with Java, which lends itself so well to automatic refactoring by a complex piece of software like Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise you to use VIM within an IDE (e.g. [VIMPlugin](http://vimplugin.org/) and Eclipse - this is the combination I use and it works very well).

I used to be a VIM diehard. However the refactoring and code analysis within a modern IDE will far surpass any capabilities that VIM will provide (with plugins etc.).

Don't get me wrong. I love VIM and still use it for all sorts of stuff. Modern IDEs are the most productive route forward, however.

Comment: I've tried those but the vim plugin doesn't give me any of the ide benefits. I might as well just use vim and the ide side by side.

Comment: modern IDEs are to heavyweight. hate waiting almost a minute to open a large project or switch workspaces.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but I was asking myself this question a bit back and decided to write one.  It's new and it not "super awesome yet" but it's written in GOLANG and it's open source. DISCLAIMER, this is my project but I am not self promoting.  I just thought I'd share with others that care about something of this nature.

https://github.com/asharif/ref

Comment: What languages does it support?

Comment: All as it is basically a recursive find/replace for both files and the file system