# How to rename a generated class during a maven build?

Tags: java, maven, refactoring, automated-refactoring

For [a project](https://github.com/Riduidel/agorava-stackoverflow) I'm working on, I send queries to StackExchange and transform the JSON result into POJOs using [jsonschema2pojo maven plugin](http://wiki.jsonschema2pojo.googlecode.com/git/site/0.3.3/generate-mojo.html). The problem is quite simple : that plugin always name the wrapper class `Data` and its contained data `Item`, when I would like wrapper to be named `*Wrapper` and the contained class `Answer` for a call to the `answers` endpoint (as an example).

Well, anyway, how could I rename the `Data` class to `AnswerWrapper` and the `Item` class to `Answer` ? I know the folder they're in, the package used to define, and so on. The only missing thing is a tool/plugin/java application to perform that operation. I was [directed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704062/are-there-any-open-source-command-line-tools-to-refactor-java-code#704103) to [JRefactory](http://jrefactory.sourceforge.net/csr-commandline.html), but the downloaded JAR doesn't look like it can provide the operation I want (and its lack of doc makes it unusable).

So, is there any more modern/efficient solution ? (or at least some I could integrate in my maven build) ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the easiest solution but one that would fit nicely with your requirements would be to actually add functionality to the maven plugin to support customizing the names of the generated classes. It would of course include building your own version and maybe submitting a patch to get it included in the mainline.

Comment: Yes, my immediate thought was "this is something the plugin should allow you to configure".

Comment: indeed a nice solution, but a long development that would drive me away from current work